# Recovery Partition Creator doesn't work

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, kernel-panic

I've a MacBook Pro5,3 with OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 and I can't access Recovery (both normal and internet mode) neither Startup Manager **without getting Kernel Panic**, even if through `diskutil list` I can see the Recovery partition installed and it seems all fine:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *525.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            524.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Since I've the same problem, model and OS described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316506/kernel-panic-on-every-attempt-to-access-recovery-mode) I've tried to use Recovery Partition Creator [v4.0.4] but at a certain point during the execution I've got two pop-up advises that said in order:

**1. mainDrive variable not defined**

**2. mainPartition not defined**

then after selecting the *OSX El Capitan Installer.app* location the program stucked at OSX ESD Installation (I see the installer drive content as shown) and currently I still can't access Recovery Mode:

[image: OSX Install ESD drive and his content page]

**What the two advises meaning? What can I do?**

Comment: I would assume if you reinstalled El Capitan on the existing El Capitan, the recovery partition would be recreated.

Comment: EDIT: I resolved by creating a bootable USB and booting into it by holding the `Alt` key at startup; I get error “No packages were eligible for install" but I found a solution by [modify system clock from terminal](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250793420) then the installation completed and I restored my data from Time Machine. Now all it works and I’m able to enter Recovery again, from what I’ve understand is a common problem due to expired Apple certificates for older OS. About Recovery Partition Creator maybe the app needs a revision by the developer. Hope to be helpful for someone.